# Kibana - Not able to start kibana on windows 10

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, java-8, kibana, kibana-6

I want to implement centralized configuration with ELK for our Spring boot microservices.

I have installed 3 different version of Kibana 6.3 , 6.7  and 7 version.
un-comment port and elasticsearch.url (used default value - elastic search running)

Getting following warning and error continuously on console

```
    log   [05:40:20.028] [warning][task_manager] 
    The task maps_telemetry "Maps-maps_telemetry" is not cancellable.
    log   [05:40:24.145] [error][security] 
    Error registering Kibana Privileges with Elasticsearch for kibana-.kibana: 
[security_exception] current license is non-compliant for [security], with { license.expired.feature="security" }
```

npm -v
5.5.1

node -v
v8.9.3

java -version
1.8.121

Your help will be appreciated to resolve this issue so that I can use kibana.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In extraction - src folder not copied so src\cli\index.js not present.

1. right clicked on zip -- properties - general tab - security -
   tick/check unblock option
2. Double clicked zip then copied folder of kibana
3. kibana run successfully

Comment: I don't get this option to unblock, I don't see that index.js file either , what can I do ? Kibana shows no error but doesn't start too

Answer (score 6):

If you run into this issue again, could you please ensure the src\cli\index.js does exist before starting Kibana?

C:\Users\44124986\data\soft\kibana-6.7.2-windows-x86_64\kibana-6.7.2-windows-x86_\src\cli\index.js

According to similar issue reported to elastic/kibana project on GitHub, the root
cause is starting Kibana before Kibana completely unzipped.

Comment: Thanks for input. Yes kibana not completely unzipped and no src folder present so got js error while starting kibana. Still kibana is not started kibana page showing "Kibana server is not ready yet". Updated error and warning of Kibana

Comment: Your new error message indicates that the x-pack security feature on your Elasticsearch has an expired license.

Comment: Elasticsearch 7.1 just made x-pack security feature free for certain type of usage. If you think you are eligible, you can upgrade your Elastic stack to 7.1 and get over the expired license problem. But check with some lawyer before do that. Or you can take out x-pack security on both Kibana and Elasticsearch.

Comment: In extraction -  src folder not copied so src\cli\index.js not present. (1) right clicked on zip -- properties - general tab - security - tick/check unblock option (2) Double clicked zip then copied folder of kibana (3) kibana run successfully

Answer (score 2):

this comment of https://stackoverflow.com/users/297907/stackoverflow solved it

In extraction - src folder not copied so src\cli\index.js not present. (1) right clicked on zip -- properties - general tab - security - tick/check unblock option (2) Double clicked zip then copied folder of kibana (3) kibana run successfully

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, I was waiting for someone to confirm.

Comment: I don't get this option to unblock, I don't see that index.js file either , what can I do ? Kibana shows no error but doesn't start too